# NEXUS 5X API23 THE emulator is not running in android device

Tags: android, android-emulator

Cannot launch AVD in emulator.
Output:

```
emulator: WARNING: VM heap size set below hardware specified minimum of 228MB
init: Could not find wglGetExtensionsStringARB!
emulator: WARNING: Setting VM heap size to 384MB
getGLES1ExtensionString: Could not find GLES 1.x config!
Hax is enabled
Failed to obtain GLES 1.x extensions string!
Hax ram_size 0x40000000
Could not initialize emulated framebufferWarning: requested ram_size 1536M too big, reduced to 1024M
HAX is working and emulator runs in fast virt mode.
console on port 5554, ADB on port 5555
emulator: ERROR: Could not initialize OpenglES emulation, use '-gpu off' to disable it.
```

Answer (score 0):

Edit ADV to set value 128 or more than 128 at VM heap of memory options

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In your AVD settings:

1. Increase VM heap size to 384Mb (as emulator sets during load)
2. Decrease RAM to 1024Mb (as emulator sets during load)
3. Uncheck "Use Host GPU" setting
4. Add SD card with size of at least 512Mb (sometime problems with startup are related to it)

Answer (score 0):

I am also using Nexus 5 and api version 23.

see my configuration is below.

[image]